# S3 web hosting for backbone.js application with pushState

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pushstate

I'm hosting a Backbone application on Amazon S3 using a custom domain name. The Backbone application router handles all routes under the root ('/'). I would like to use pushState, so there's no need for the # prefix on my application routes.
Basically, i want all sub-routes to be routed by S3 to the domain root and let Backbone do the rest.

I added the following rule:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
    <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals >
     </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>mydomain.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

But this just adds the # sign prefix to all my sub-routes. I want to avoid that.

How do I set the redirection rules on my S3 bucket to route everything to the indexed document without having to add the #?

Answer (score 0):

Use bucket URL instead of your domain URL:

`<HostName>BUCKET_NAME.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>`

Also check you anchor links dont have # in url `<a href="#home">Home</a>` instead have links like this:

```
<a href="/home">Home</a>
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

Then using jQuery you can navigate the link to router

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="/"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
    Backbone.history.navigate(href, { trigger: true });
});
```